# React unit testing anonymous function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test an onChange anonymous function, which changes a value in my textbox. I want to verify that if the function inside onChange gets called, the state is changed. The function itself is simple:

```
onChange={(e) => this.setState({someState: e.value})}
```

If the function had a name, I would do something like the following:

```
         test('myFunction should change someState value', () => {

                 const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent/>);
                 const instance = wrapper.instance();

                const mockEvent = {
                    target:{
                        value: "some value in textbox"
                     }        
                   };

                const expectedValue = "some value in textbox";

                instance.myFunction(mockEvent);
                expect(wrapper.state().someState).toEqual(expectedValue)

              });
```

Since the function is anonymous, I don't know how to call it with instance. I'd prefer not to give the function a name because i don't want the testing to affect my code. What would be a good solution?

Comment: Is there something visually about the component's presentation that changes when `someState` changes? A piece of text or list or something else? That would be a way to indirectly assert that the state has changed, in a user-focused way.

Comment: @JakeWorth In this case, only the text in the textbox should change.

Comment: You need to trigger change event, then you can assert that `state().someState` has been changed, or DOM has been changed. *I'd prefer not to give the function a name because i don't want the testing to affect my code* - it's not a good thing at all to do this for testability reasons, and another good thing is that passing the same prop every time to `onChange` allows for optimization you won't get from anonymous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to test this case. E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      someValue: '',
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <input type="text" onChange={(e) => this.setState({ someValue: e.target.value })}></input>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```js
import MyComponent from './';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';

describe('61597604', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent></MyComponent>);
    const mEvent = { target: { value: 'ok' } };
    wrapper.find('input').simulate('change', mEvent);
    expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual({ someValue: 'ok' });
  });

  it('should pass 2', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent></MyComponent>);
    const input = wrapper.find('input').getElement();
    const mEvent = { target: { value: 'ok' } };
    input.props.onChange(mEvent);
    expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual({ someValue: 'ok' });
  });
});
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61597604/index.test.tsx (8.059s)
  61597604
    ✓ should pass (13ms)
    ✓ should pass 2 (1ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.213s
```